# How to backup database with 100 rows in each table?

Tags: sql-server

I want to backup a SQL Server database with all the objects along with data but data in all the tables should be limited that is 100 rows for each table. I can do this in mysql very easily but in SQL Server I don`t know how to do??

Comment: That's not backup, that's exporting the data. Backup's primary purpose is disaster recovery, it doesn't make sense to limit the number of records. What are you trying to accomplish? What commands/tools did you use with MySQL?

Comment: While you can technically do this, how are you going to make use of 100 rows from each table? Is there absolutely no referential integrity at all? (I suspect you couldn't pull 100 customers and 100 orders without violating some integrity or writing very complex statements.)

Comment: It makes sense if you have a 10 TB database and just need a simple version to work on it. And as far as I found, there is no easy solution for SQL Server

Answer (score 5):

You can't really use an explicit `BACKUP DATABASE` for this. However you could do something like this - however keep in mind that - as in my comment - this data will be of limited use if you are relying on any sort of data integrity since the ordering will be relatively arbitrary and unless everything is 1:1 and you happen to get magically convenient sorting on all the queries it will just be a massive hodge podge of data:

```
CREATE DATABASE copy_of_original;
GO

USE original_db;
GO

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'';

-- this assumes all tables are in `dbo` schema:
SELECT @sql = @sql + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
  + 'SELECT TOP (100) * INTO copy_of_original.dbo.' 
  + QUOTENAME(name) + ' FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';'
FROM sys.tables
WHERE schema_id = 1;

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Once you're done this, you can backup `copy_of_original` - but keep in mind it will not have any of the indexes or constraints present in the original database, and that `TOP` will have picked an arbitrary set of 100 rows from each table (or the whole table, for small tables with less than 100 rows).

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server I would use the tool "bcp"

This requires a bit of coding though: generating the top 100 select statement for each table and creating a batch file

Comment: sample using ***PowerShell via BCP by using a TOP 100 clause in the query*** ?

Comment: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/automated-script-generation-with-powershell-and-smo/

Answer (score 0):

You may please try this solution

1. Please Create a copy of your database
2. Execute the below code in your DB copy to delete rows from table having more than 100 rows.

   sp_msforeachtable
   'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
   ;WITH [DUMMYTABLE] AS 
   (SELECT   RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()),  * FROM ?)
    DELETE FROM [DUMMYTABLE] WHERE RN > 100
    ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
3. Back Up your new database.

**Limitation :** *Issue in data integrity of the backed up database as we disable constraints and delete rows from the database.*

Comment: Another limitation: `ORDER BY NEWID()` will potentially be quite expensive on larger tables. I wouldn't suggest it unless there is an explicit requirement for *random* rows. Furthermore copying all the data only to delete 90+% of it does not seem like an efficient path (I'd hate to see the transaction log for the new database when this operation is finished).