# select first 100 rows in a tables of 10000 records and back it up - postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called **customer table** made up of 21 fields namely firstname, lastname, sex, gender, occupation, address just to mention a few.

My challenge is to select the first top 100 rows and back it up in a .backup format as a life test data.

Please how can I achieve this.

Comment: Explain what you have tried already

Comment: iI have googled and found this >>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913292/how-to-backup-database-with-100-rows-in-each-table

Comment: `create table as select * from orgi_table order by .. limit 1000` or `copy(select * from orgi_table order by .. limit 1000) to 'csv.file`

Comment: What is this ".backup format" you are referring to?

Comment: "My Challenge" => homework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the `COPY` command with a query, e. g.:

```
COPY (SELECT a.id, a.name FROM a ORDER BY a.id LIMIT 100) TO 'a.txt';
```